# Routing to other url in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am currently working on a project where I have CRUD operation using node.js and mysql.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "database",
  user: "admin",
  password: "pass",
  database: "db"
});

var app = express();


con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM shops where id =33", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});

app.use('/shop', function(err) {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM shops where id =34", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
});

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

I want to get the shops data using localhost:3000/shops and brands data using localhost:3000/brands. But i don't know how to do that because i am very new in node.js. Infact,Today i my first day. I someone gives me som demo project or some thing like this. I will be very thankful.

Comment: If this is your first time working with Node.js and Express then it is most probably too soon to start asking questions here. You should **read/watch some tutorials** on how the express framework works. There are thousands of them all over the internet.

Comment: You are right but I was exploring NodeJs from last two weeks. And I only need this to connect my unity app to aws server means only CRUD operation. But now i hav done it. ('--').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/brands',(req,res) =>{
//inside query
})

like...thiss
```